# How to load CSS ( wp_enqueue_style() ) if sub_field of flexible fields used in page template

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I need to load CSS only if sub_field of flexible fields group is in use on a page template.
For example:

```
$flexable = get_field('flexable_fields');
foreach( $flexable as $item ){
if($item['title']){
wp_enqueue_style('title-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/css/title-style.css'), false);
}
}
```

Which hook I need to use to implement this, "init" or something else?
Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure, `flexable_fields` is a [Flexible Content](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/) field? And what *sub field* are you evaluating? What kind of field is the sub field?

Answer (score 0):

The most suitable hook to use would be  `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    $flexable = get_field('flexable_fields');
    foreach( $flexable as $item ){
        if($item['title']){
            wp_enqueue_style('title-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/css/title-style.css'), false);
        }
    }
});
```